# Bug report for conversion to SSL

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, ssl

After the conversion of all outgoing links to HTTPS, I now get this error.

> [image]

I get that error for, near as I can tell, for any page rooted at `http://stackexchange.com/` but not for subdomains, such as `http://meta.stackexchange.com/`. The offending source is `<script src="https://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script>`. (around line 1345 for the home page.) This only shows up in my Konqueror browser, which seems to be stricter than Firefox, which doesn't complain when loading the SE pages, but does give and error if I directly load the offending URL. (Possible bug, or security issue with Firefox.) Interestingly enough, that tag is absent in the HTTPS version of the same pages, so I don't know how it would respond when the browser is supposed to check the page for mixed content.

Retrieving the certificate offered from that URL yields

> ```
> Certificate:
>     Data:
>         Version: 3 (0x2)
>         Serial Number:
>             63:b9:ec:7e:ff:98:83:35:f1:13:d6:7d:2f:86:4d:35
>     Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
>         Issuer: C=US, O=Symantec Corporation, OU=Symantec Trust Network, CN=Symantec Class 3 ECC 256 bit SSL CA - G2
>         Validity
>             Not Before: Jul 28 00:00:00 2016 GMT
>             Not After : Jul 28 23:59:59 2017 GMT
>         Subject: C=US, ST=Massachusetts, L=Cambridge, O=Akamai Technologies, Inc., CN=a248.e.akamai.net
>         Subject Public Key Info:
>             Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
>                 Public-Key: (256 bit)
>                 pub: 
>                     04:02:a6:fc:13:cd:66:f5:ba:aa:2c:a8:4e:76:22:
>                     d3:ee:90:7e:b3:61:bc:75:1a:3b:d3:c7:80:60:1c:
>                     6b:a5:45:d8:2d:f6:9b:27:1f:26:cb:2e:fe:34:e2:
>                     35:d2:9a:dd:4a:92:2b:4f:eb:19:a8:90:10:38:a9:
>                     bd:47:66:74:2b
>                 ASN1 OID: prime256v1
>                 NIST CURVE: P-256
>         X509v3 extensions:
>             X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
>                 DNS:*.akamaihd.net, DNS:*.akamaihd-staging.net, DNS:*.akamaized-staging.net, DNS:*.akamaized.net, DNS:a248.e.akamai.net
>             X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
>                 CA:FALSE
>             X509v3 Key Usage: critical
>                 Digital Signature
>             X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
>                 Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.2
>                 CPS: https://d.symcb.com/cps
>                 User Notice:
>                     Explicit Text: https://d.symcb.com/rpa
>
>             X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 
>
>                 Full Name:
>                 URI:http://rc.symcb.com/rc.crl
>
>             X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
>                 TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
>             X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
>                 keyid:25:F0:8A:E1:4B:7A:D9:01:95:0A:ED:C6:53:F1:8C:78:1F:D9:F3:F8
>
>             Authority Information Access: 
>                 OCSP - URI:http://rc.symcd.com
>                 CA Issuers - URI:http://rc.symcb.com/rc.crt
>
>             CT Precertificate SCTs: 
>                 Signed Certificate Timestamp:
>                     Version   : v1(0)
>                     Log ID    : DD:EB:1D:2B:7A:0D:4F:A6:20:8B:81:AD:81:68:70:7E:
>                                 2E:8E:9D:01:D5:5C:88:8D:3D:11:C4:CD:B6:EC:BE:CC
>                     Timestamp : Jul 28 20:05:03.628 2016 GMT
>                     Extensions: none
>                     Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
>                                 30:45:02:21:00:D2:39:E1:01:CD:38:CA:D3:2A:C1:CA:
>                                 73:76:17:A9:0E:89:71:93:8F:CB:CB:4D:73:ED:36:F3:
>                                 86:B7:44:9B:AF:02:20:30:68:AA:47:C7:79:47:FF:12:
>                                 0C:B8:0D:CE:96:B4:5E:DD:E1:86:B3:E9:54:30:B4:F6:
>                                 6D:13:AD:A7:62:86:D6
>                 Signed Certificate Timestamp:
>                     Version   : v1(0)
>                     Log ID    : A4:B9:09:90:B4:18:58:14:87:BB:13:A2:CC:67:70:0A:
>                                 3C:35:98:04:F9:1B:DF:B8:E3:77:CD:0E:C8:0D:DC:10
>                     Timestamp : Jul 28 20:05:03.721 2016 GMT
>                     Extensions: none
>                     Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
>                                 30:45:02:21:00:B6:6B:FF:58:30:04:90:8C:CF:A0:09:
>                                 8D:83:CA:C3:07:78:71:8E:BA:83:13:6F:0E:F7:2A:5C:
>                                 1D:F2:DF:0C:A4:02:20:09:1E:C7:3B:65:B2:5A:3D:BE:
>                                 F8:3C:F1:DA:DA:1C:B0:05:9F:A2:DE:84:E2:9A:F8:20:
>                                 E6:1B:EE:E2:06:C8:52
>     Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
>         30:45:02:21:00:9a:2c:bc:7b:38:29:8e:52:13:60:a1:95:ff:
>         b3:aa:72:1b:31:38:a7:97:45:88:b2:49:9b:7b:ba:74:3c:3f:
>         8d:02:20:4b:cb:c1:d5:16:5e:bd:ec:9c:84:c6:d7:0c:fa:f1:
>         e7:2f:d6:1e:f7:cf:cb:19:42:92:f1:d0:47:d4:d7:d7:9a
> ```

I don't know if the URL is co-owned with the subject of the certificate or not, but I'm not adding exceptions for miss-configured servers.

I realize that this is part of the overall migration to HTTPS for SE site-wide, and I expect that there will be other problems/bug to track down. In that vein, I'm not complaining about the error. Rather, I'm raising it so that the developers can track down problems and correct them. In this case it probably involves getting the third-party site to correct their issues.

This seemed like the best place to raise the issue. If it's better raised elsewhere, please tell me where and I can post it there instead.

Comment: In Chrome I only get this error in the dev console, but yeah something is broken in there. Thanks for the report! :)

Comment: The website https://www.whynopadlock.com shows a large number of HTTP assets on that page.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen The items found are links not yet converted to HTTPS on the HTTPS version of the home page. All are Gravatar images. The problem here is on the _HTTP_ pages with a link that _is_ HTTPS, but that serves an invalid certificate. It's a problem SE will have to get that site to fix. Because it's part of their metrics, I believe, it's also a link they can't "just drop" to avoid page load errors. SE needs it to work for their benefit, not mine. It has to be fixed - at the source, not on SE -  so the sooner they know, the longer they have to get the other site to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

This should behave correctly in the latest version of all sites - we're `https://` across the board with Q&A now.